# requirejs optimize html and remove from dist

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a requirejs configuration that uses !text plugin.
When I run optimize, it works pefectly, but requirejs also copies all html files.

If I try to use

```
fileExclusionRegExp: /.*\.html/
```

then text plugin raise error

```
text!views/main.html: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory ...
```

Are there some way to no copy html files to destination dir without raise text plugin error?

This is my config:

```
baseUrl: 'js',
appDir: 'src',
dir: 'dist',
mainConfigFile: 'src/main.js',
keepBuildDir: false,
optimize: "uglify2",
generateSourceMaps: true,
removeCombined: true,
preserveLicenseComments: false,
fileExclusionRegExp: /.*\.less|.*\.html/,
paths: {
  'main': '../main',
},
modules: [
  {
    name: "main",
    include: ['requirejs']
  }
],
optimizeAllPluginResources: true
```

Comment: why do you not want to copy the html files, how do you suppose text plugin will work without the `main.html`.

Comment: text requirejs compiles html to html.js and include it in optimized file as string